# Can't remove CouchDB

Tags: 11.04, package-management, uninstall, couchdb

Under 11.04, when I do `sudo couchdb -V`, I get a response like "couchdb - Apache CouchDB 1.1.1".  When I do `couchdb -V`, without sudo, I get that no package/program like that is installed.  I've tried doing `sudo apt-get remove couchdb` and `purge` too, but I can't make `couchdb` disappear. When doing a `dpkg -l | grep couchdb`, I get:

```
rc  couchdb                               1.0.1-0ubuntu15                            RESTful document oriented database, system DB
rc  couchdb-bin                           1.0.1-0ubuntu15                            RESTful document oriented database, programs
```

I don't understand what's the actual situation, or how can I try to solve this.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I want couchdb, but my version seems to be full of errors so I was hoping to be able to reinstall it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rc status means:

> r: package has been removed
>
> c: configuration files are still there

To remove that packages completely try this :

```
sudo dpkg --purge couchdb
```

Comment: When I try that I get an error message like so (the jist is that it can't seem to stop the couchdb server.):

sudo dpkg --purge couchdb 
(Reading database ... 212630 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing couchdb ...
 * Stopping database server couchdb                               [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript couchdb, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing couchdb (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
 * Starting database server couchdb                                   [ OK ] 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 couchdb

Comment: This is not directly related with this subject. But you can try this. `sudo mkdir /var/log/couchdb/0.10.0` and                  
`sudo chown couchdb:couchdb /var/log/couchdb/0.10.0` After that just try to stop couch db: `sudo /etc/init.d/couchch stop` And try to uninstall it again. via: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/couchdb/+bug/453049/comments/10